# Error in chrome.storage.local.get callback function

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension that hides/shows a menu bar on a certain domain and remembers per page whether it should be hidden. To save this persistently I use the chrome.storage.local API but I get these weird errors now.

> Error in response to storage.get: Error: Invalid value for argument 1.
>   Property 'tabId': Property is required.
>       at updateBar (chrome-extension://hoeijlfnppcfdokpgeafimggcbclpfhb/background.js:11:23)
>       at checkForValidUrl (chrome-extension://hoeijlfnppcfdokpgeafimggcbclpfhb/background.js:5:3)
>   extensions::sendRequest:26

The weird thing is that I never ask for tabId in the storage get and my callback function for that also requires no tabId whatsoever. It seems that the nesting of these callback functions could do something wrong. And even though there are errors, the extension seems to work just fine...

Here is my background page:

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('http://www.au.dk') > -1) {
        // ... show the page action.
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        updateBar(false, tab);

    }
}

function updateBar(toggle, tab){
    chrome.storage.local.get(tab.url, function(res){
        var obj = {};
        //toggle the visibility if necessary
        if(toggle){
            console.log(res[tab.url]);
            obj[tab.url] = !res[tab.url];
            chrome.storage.local.set(obj);
        }
        else
            obj[tab.url] = res[tab.url];

        //send request to content page and update pageAction icon
        if(obj[tab.url]){
            console.log(res[tab.url]);
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id,{req:"hide"}, function(){});
            chrome.pageAction.setIcon({path:"iconShown.png"});
        }
        else{
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id,{req:"show"}, function(){});
            chrome.pageAction.setIcon({path:"iconHidden.png"});

        }
        if(res[tab.url] == undefined){
            obj[tab.url] = false;
            chrome.storage.local.set(obj);
        }
    });
}
// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    updateBar(true, tab);
});
```

Comment: If my answer below helped you with your problem, please mark is as "accepted".

Comment: Weird. Why would chrome.storage.local.get throw `Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'tabId': Property is required` when its asking for [a dictionary specifying default values](http://archive.is/1Tq4j#selection-3691.46-3691.84)?

Comment: @user307, Did you replace `chrome.storage.local` with another object?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the deprecated **[`chrome.tabs.sendRequest`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendRequest)**, instead of the recommended **[`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)**.

---

Second, you are probably unaware of the fact that multiple **[`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)** events will be triggered for a single tab navigation operations. (E.g. one when the status is *loading*, one when the status is *complete*, one when the *favicon* has been loaded etc).
In that respect, it makes more sense (and helps avoid unpredected behaviour and unnecessary workload) to perform your checks only when the tab has finished loading:

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status !== 'complete') {
        /* `.status` is either 'undefined' (meaning the tab's status
         * has not changed - maybe it was just the favicon)
         * or it equals "loading"
        return;
    }
    if (tab.url.indexOf('http://www.au.dk') > -1) {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Finally, regarding the `id` property of a **[`chrome.tabs.Tab`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab)**, keep in mind that:

> [...] **Under some circumstances a Tab may not be assigned an ID**, for example when querying foreign tabs using the sessions API, in which case a session ID may be present.